# Get ListView bound data on click event ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm trying to get the values of the data bounded to the EditItemTemplate, on an event.
The ListView id is lvProducts, how do I refer the item's data in the UpdateButton_Click method?

This is the edit item template:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                         <tr>
                            <td class="narrow"><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ProductID")%>' ID="idLabel"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td class="wide"><asp:Textbox runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ProductTitle")%>' ID="nameEdit"></asp:Textbox><span style="color:red">*</span></td>
                            <td class="narrow"><asp:Textbox runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("StockAmount")%>' TextMode="Number" ID="Label4"></asp:Textbox></td>
                            <td class="narrow"><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("AvailableAmount")%>' ID="faxEdit"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td class="narrow"><asp:Checkbox runat="server" Checked='<%#Bind("ProductStatus")%>' Enabled="true" ID="Label6"></asp:Checkbox></td>
                            <td class="wide" style="text-align:center;"> <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" ToolTip='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>' OnClick="UpdateButton_Click" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save" />&nbsp;
                                 <asp:LinkButton ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
```

C#:

```
 protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
???
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havnt tested but it should be something like this:

```
     protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Cancel")
    {
        ListViewDataItem lvd = (ListViewDataItem)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;

        //Same two lines for each value
        Label ID = lvd.FindControl("idLabel") as Label;
        string id = id.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, just one comment: I changed the second line to: ListViewDataItem lvd = lvProducts.Items[i]

Answer (score 1):

Set the CommandArgument for your button to the ProductId (assuming that's your primary key).

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" ToolTip='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>' OnClick="UpdateButton_Click" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>' CommandName="Update" Text="Save" />
```

Then get the primary key from the button in the event. And use that to load the data, make your updates, and save to database.

```
protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn=sender as LinkButton;
    string productid=btn.CommandArgument;
    //now update your data
}
```

Comment: This one is great also, I might use this way too. Thanks